# Sum value for outer group

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 2008 to put together a report.  I've got two views:  One, a list of orders, the second, a list of line items.

The orders are grouped by location.
The line items are grouped by order.

Report Header - suppressed
Page Header - suppressed
Group Header #1 - Reports which location we're at.  (new page before)
Group Header #2 - Reports which order we're looking at.
Details:  Gives the line item information
 *  Has Line Item Price
Group Footer #2 - gives the order summary
 *  Subtotal:  Running Total (Line Item Price) - reset after group 2.
 *  Fright (column from order view)
 *  Total (sums the above)
Group Footer #1 - gives the summary for that location
 * Complete Subtotal:  Running Total (Line Item Price) - reset after
   group 1
 * Complete Freight:  Sum (Freight)
 * Grand Total (Sums the above)

The problem comes up with `Complete Freight` - everything else is working great.  `Complete Freight` is not summing up the freight charges the way I want them to.  It is summing the freight once per line item view, not once per order view.

for instance, that there are two orders in the report - each of them has three line items.  The first order has `Freight` charge of $10.  The second has a `Freight` charge of $15.  The `Complete Freight` should be $25 - the sum of the two.  Instead, I get a `Complete Freight` of $75 (3 x $10 + 3 x $15).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of duplication.

One order has many line items and when you place the order data beside line order will be repeated as many times as the line items.

Your approach of summarization is wrong.. Instead of summary you add running totals for every group to calculate order summary.